# Copy edited values before they are edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setup a daily report that will send me an email with only the edited rows from a sheet, but also including the old values before they were edited.

I wrote the following script, where when the specified range is edited, the whole row is transferred to another tab called "new_values".

```
function onEdit_inRange(e,sheetName,sheetRange){
    var sh=e.range.getSheet();
    if(sh.getName()===sheetName){
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(sheetRange);
        var xy=[e.range.getColumn(),e.range.getRow()];
        if (xy[0]>=range.getColumn() && xy[0]<=range.getLastColumn() && xy[1]>=range.getRow() && xy[1]<=range.getLastRow()) {
            return e.range;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function onEdit(e){
    var range=0;
    if((range=onEdit_inRange(e,'sheet','M6:O'))){
      //  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You Edited a Cell INSIDE the Range!');

    } else if ((range=onEdit_inRange(e,'sheet','Q6:Q'))) {
     //   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You Edited a Cell INSIDE the Range!');
    }
   var ss = e.range.getSheet();
  //ss.getRange(e.range.getRow(),49)  //set timestamp in column 49
  //.setValue(new Date()); // Set time of edit in "G"
   var appendSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('new_values');
   var archiveLastRow = appendSheet.getLastRow();
       Logger.log(archiveLastRow);
   var archiveAppendRange = "new_values!" + (appendSheet.getLastRow() + 1) + ":" + (appendSheet.getLastRow() + 1);
       Logger.log(archiveAppendRange);
   var destRange = ss.getRange(archiveAppendRange);
       Logger.log(destRange);
   var sourceDataValues = ss.getRange(range.getRow(),1,1,49).copyTo(destRange);
       Logger.log(sourceDataValues);

}
```

What I can't manage to do is to make this script to also copy the old values, when they are edited, and move them to another separate tab (called "old_values").

How can I copy the old value, when cells are edited in the same way I do the new values?

My plan is that I'll merge both tables and send over email.

Here's an example spreadsheet with my code: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xzyVD7ElA0FMVC8sta6beDJCIwOQEMRqjhF5eW4mExI/copy

Comment: Have you researched event objects? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation.

Comment: `e.value` and `e.oldValue` [both exist for `onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)